# Check list for duplications with exceptional of empty strings items

Tags: c#

My code to check whether list contains duplicates:

```
//nummers is List<string>
if (nummers.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1))
{
}
```

however on my list there could be empty string items (many) i do not want to take them into consideration. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two quick options are

```
nummers.GroupBy(n => n).Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Key)).Any(c => c.Count() > 1)
```

or

```
nummers.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Key)).GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1)
```

Either should do the trick. I'll leave it up to you to check which performs better

Or use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` if you want to ignore strings that are just whitespace too

Answer (score 2):

filter them out

```
//nummers is List<string>
if (nummers.Where(n=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n)).GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1))
{
}
```

Comment: instead of stringIsNullOrEmpty you ment : string.IsNullOrEmpty(n) ? P.S if i would like also to exclude other string with empty strings?

Answer (score 1):

The most straight-forward way of doing this would be to just filter them out before you group them, like this:

`nummers.Where(n => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n)).GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1)`